# XMLHttpRequest POST Form Inputs not parsed with Promises

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise, xmlhttprequest, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to implement XHR POST request with ES2015 Promises on localserver with this [json-server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server). When I submit the Form with `onsubmit` event server doesn't receive any data as if the Form was empty. But If I throw an Error( `throw SyntaxError;` //or `console.log(undefinedVar)`) before executing my Promise Object data gets posted to the server as intended. I tried `setTimeout` to introduce a little delay between `onsubmit` event and Promise execution. But even that doesn't work.xhr. I tried `send(new FormData(data));` before sending HTMLElement Form directly as data but that posts empty form too.

I'm new to async in JS is there a requirement for some sort of delay in Promises? Or what I'm doing wrong?

The Code where I need to insert an error.

```
function submitForm(form_Data) {

throw SyntaxError; //THE REQUIRED ERROR

getData(form_Data.method, form_Data.action, form_Data).then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});}
```

Complete Code:

```js
"use strict";


function getData(method, url, data) {
 return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open(method, url, true);
  xhr.onload = function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
    resolve(xhr.response);
   } else {
    reject({
     status: this.status,
     statusText: this.statusText
    });
   }
  };
  xhr.onerror = function () {
   reject({
    status: this.status,
    statusText: this.statusText
   });
  };
  xhr.send(data);
 });
}


function submitForm(form_Data) {
 throw SyntaxError;

 getData(form_Data.method, form_Data.action, form_Data).then((res) => {
  console.log(res);
 }).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
 });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Ajax</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h2>Json and Ajax</h2>
    <form id="formFirst" method="POST" action="http://localhost:3000/posts" onsubmit="submitForm(this); return false;">

      <input id="input1" name="input1" type="text">

      <input id="input2" name="input2" type="text">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </header>

  <script src="js/main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Throwing an error causes the JavaScript to abort, so the event handler never returns, and the form submits as normal. This is just like not having any JS at all.

---

The JS is failing to submit the form data because you are passing `send` an HTMLFormElement object, which isn't supported.

You need to construct a [FormData object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).

```
xhr.send(new FormData(data));
```

Comment: I used this too but FormData returns empty object always.

Comment: the same HTMLFormElement that I'm passing now as data I used to pass to FormData contructer but doesn't work. It returns empty

Comment: check the browsers developer tools network tab - you should see that the form data is being sent - don't believe `console.log(new FormData(data))` if that's what you are doing, because the output will "look" like an empty FromData object

Comment: Tried it again and No It still sends the empty form. An entry gets logged on  the server with no data. and I was using a variable to store and log FormData Obj. Now I did directly in `xhr.send(new FormData(data));`